# Invisibly rewriting root to subdirectory using mod_rewrite (ajaxplorer)

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, pydio

I've been looking on various sites reading mod_rewrite examples for a few hours, and have used it many times before successfully... but I'm trying something new with it now and can't for the life of me get it working!

I'm using a PHP file manager tool called `AjaXplorer`, I have it in a subdirectory on the root of my server `/ajaxplorer-core-4.0.4`. When I go to the root of my site `http://domain.com/` I want it to invisibly redirect to the `/ajaxplorer-core-4.0.4` folder (but still show the root domain in the address bar).

I still want to be able to access the other files/directories on the root as normal just typing in the path.

I assume this is possible? Seems relatively simple but I just can't get it working.

AjaXplorer seems to load js files and images etc from `/ajaxplorer-core-4.0.4/plugins`, I have a feeling that's where it's tripping me up.

Any pointers would be massively appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found it on another answer luckily :)

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?site.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdir/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdir/$1 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?site.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subdir/index.php [L]
```

Comment: THis works great when pretty permalinks are not enabled. If we enable permalinks, how can we make sure that www.domain.com/section1 -> www.domain.com/wordpress/section1 without returning erro404 ?

Comment: Well I think I solved this problem. The .htaccess file in the /wordpress directory has to be edited, just after you enable pretty permalinks: The line `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]` should be changed to `RewriteRule . wordpress_subdir/index.php [L]`

Answer (score 0):

- Here's the wiki of [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-as)
- The [howto's htaccess official guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html)
- The [official mod_rewrite guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

And if that's not enough:

### Two hints:

If you're **not** in a hosted environment (= if it's *your own server* and *you **can** modify the virtual hosts*, not only the `.htaccess` files), try to use the `RewriteLog` directive: it helps you to track down such problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

---

My favorite tool to check for regexp:

http://www.quanetic.com/Regex (don't forget to choose ereg(POSIX) instead of preg(PCRE)!)

Comment: All my links (and suggestions are both about syntax *and* logic)